# Have Serverless always run `npm i` at deploy?

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

Using Serverless and AWS Node Lambdas I've noticed that when running the local deployment, e.g. `sls deploy --stage test` it is using the local `node_modules` directory and not running a "fresh" `npm i` prior to deploying.

Is there any "Serverless way" to do this or is `rm -r node_modules && npm i && sls deploy -s test` the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

"Is there any "Serverless way" to do this" No, I think so!

You can create an npm script to do that:

`package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
  "deploy:test": "rm -r node_modules && npm i && sls deploy -s test"
}
...
```

Now, you can run `npm run deploy:test`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I already have... :) Just figured it would be a rather common request that there was some work-around...

Answer (score 0):

One option you could explore would be building your own plugin which hooks the `deploy:initialize` lifecycle hook and runs `npm i`.

You can read more at the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/blog/writing-serverless-plugins)

Comment: Thanks but a bit of a hassle as it can be done with a few commands...